# How do I stop body scrolling in HTML?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I am trying to disable body scrolling when a modal is opened. 
I've tried every method but nothing worked for me. When a modal is opened 
css property

```
overflow:hidden
```

gets applied to body, but even then background scrolls. However the scroll bar disappears when a modal is opened.

Comment: Can you share the code you're using to achieve this in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Have you looked at the Bootstrap Modal Live Demo? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#live-demo

Comment: @Simplicity - The thing is I am adding this feature to an existing code which already has its css defined. Sorry but since the code is so sophisticated I cannot share it. I just wish to know in what conditions can the above mentioned problem arise ?

Comment: @AnkitSahu It sounds like the issue of scrolling is not on part the Modals fault but perhaps Javascript somewhere else capturing the scrolling events and moving the page? When the modal opens the focus is moved from the body to the modal meaning any scrolling will happen there and not on the page. I suggest checking your modal code to make sure it's getting focus correct as described by the link I posted previously.

Comment: @AnkitSahu - I've been playing around with a bootstrap modal in a jsfiddle, and an overflowing div, but for me the modal already blocks the scrolling of the page, so as Daniel said, it might be Javascript capturing the scrolling events and moving the page.

Comment: @DanielTung : You were right. Actually my webpage is using parallax effects. That is what causing this problem. When I do not load parallax.js everything works perfectly. 
But with parallax.js file loaded problem appears. Is there any way I can keep both functionalities. i.e parallax as well as modal scrolling ?